# In Google Chrome browser, why does Gmail use so much of the CPU when hardware acceleration is enabled?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, cpu, gmail

Here's a screenshot of the issue.

On the right, Windows Task Manager showing high Chrome CPU usage.
On the left, Chrome's Task Manager showing it's all coming from the Gmail tab.
[image]

If Hardware Acceleration is turned OFF in Chrome settings, Gmail uses 1-3% CPU when idle.
[image]

To isolate that it isn't a combination of Hardware Acceleration and something else I've tried:

1. Disabled all plugins.
2. Clearing cookies
3. Incognito Tab

The Gmail tab will use 45-50% cpu as long as it's the *foreground tab* and Hardware Acceleration is enabled in Chrome.

Why is this happening?  It doesn't make sense that an idol page should consume more than a very small amount of CPU time.

P.S. - I'm running Windows and this gmail cpu spike doesn't happen in Firefox or Internet Explorer.

Comment: If I were to guess.  Chrome is using your CPU for the hardware acceleration.

Comment: Yes, but why? I have 25 other tabs open and none of them do.  It's weird that Gmail needs to constantly churn when it's not doing anything.

Comment: what is the tab in question doing something like Facebook/ other SNS?  Those are much more  frequently than people realize investigating and re-drawing pages.

Comment: "Hardware acceleration" is kind of vague about what kind of hardware it using, but I've always assumed it was graphical in nature, so I doubt there is much gain to be found in gmail, where most of the heavy lifting it is doing is going to be network traffic.

Comment: If I recall correctly, Chrome sets the system timer to 1ms instead of 15.625ms unless you're running on battery. This may have something to do with it.